# MeMenu not indicating new mail

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, email, memenu

The MeMenu used to change color when new e-mails arrived. With 11.10 and now 12.04, this is no longer the case. As I understand, this is due to the default use of Thunderbird instead of Evolution. Is it possible to restore this functionality with Thunderbird or is it necessary to install Evolution? If the latter, is it a simple matter of installing it, or is there tweaking that must be done? I see this question has been asked many times before, but it appears that no one has answered it yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The package for Evolution integration that has to be installed is

#### [evolution-indicator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/evolution-indicator) [image: Install evolution-indicator]